# HTML5 filesystem API - random writes to a large file

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I am playing around with HTML5 filesystem API. I want to write to a large file in chunks at random positions. Let's say I have a chunk in memory, but it happens to be in the middle of that large file. Is it possible to create the file using filesystem API with a specified size upfront (filled with null bytes for instance)? I think that would allow me to `seek` to a proper place. I tried `writer.seek(randomPosition)` before writing to an empty file, but the length and the position of the writer remain 0. If that's not possible I will just append the chunks in proper order.

Comment: wasn't the filesystem API retired a few years ago? are you sure that whatever browser you're using still implements it and the implementation is full and _correct_?

Comment: I am aware of its limitations/pitfalls. It is abandoned by W3C but it is implemented in chrome. I don't know of any plans of removing it from chrome. I don't know if it is fully correct either. And there is a IndexedDB polyfill for other browsers (which might lead me towards IndexedDB altogether). However all of this is not that relevant to the question I asked.